# How to remote access Oracle 12c using SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-sql-developer, connections

The listener has started correctly and its status shows OK!

I enter the correct IP address of the server in the `listener.ora` file, not `localhost`.

But when I try to connect to my database by entering the following in SQL Developer:

```
user: system
password: *******

host: 54.215.5.46
port: 1521
SID: orcl
```

I get this error:

> Statut : échec -Echec du test : Erreur d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

I think that I need to open the 1521 port but I don't know if this is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the following in-order to connect to remote database:

1. Make sure server is accessible from client side, easiest way to do it by using `ping` command to verify.
2. There is a connection between host and server using a specific port, you can use `telnet` command to verify.
3. Enable the instance listener to be listening on an IP address not `localhost`.
4. Database is running

Comment: Step 1 is Okay !
Step 2: when I do this command `telnet 32.15.48.2 1521` from the server or another linux I got this error:

Comment: from the server:
`telnet: connect to address 32.15.48.2: Connection refused`
and from another linux client:
`telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host`

Steps 3: it's OKay I put the IP adress in the `listener.ora` file
Steps 4: Okay the databes is running

Comment: you need to check your firewall, make sure the connection is accepted.

Comment: THANKS YOU A LOT guys, It was the firewall ^^ The port 1521 and 5500 wasn't open on my server. I open it by doing `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=1521/tcp`